# How do I fade in :focus when an input box is selected?

Tags: jquery, focus, fadein

I'm trying to work out how to fade in the :focus pseudo selector when an input box is selected.

I've tried the following method but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't think I've set the parameters properly so some help would be welcome here.

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $('input').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('input').focus();
    });
});​
```

Comment: How do you mean "fade in"? Your current code starts showing the element when it's clicked - but then it must already be visible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WwetH/6/ - Here is the example I'm working on...

Comment: It does not animate the fadeIn, because it's already visible!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is feasible. The outline is 0, 1 or 2px big, so the animation is quite choppy: http://jsfiddle.net/WwetH/7/.

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was trying to achieve. If you speed it up then the animation is sharper.

Comment: Hey, @user1691585 , in your jsfiddle you are using Mootools, not jQuery and that's the problem!

Comment: True I was although the code wasn't quite right anyway, I'll remember that for future reference though, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but maybe this could be the solution:

```
jQuery('input').on('focus', function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

So what happens is you check your inputbox and add a listener when you focus on it.
Then you tell jQuery when it happens the box has to fade in. When you want to do this
on all inputboxes on your page, the safest way to do it is like this:

```
jQuery('input').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).on('focus', function() {
        jQuery(this).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```